# What does Preference.setSummary() do?

Tags: android

In my code I've used the `Preference.setSummary()` method to change the summary line of a setting to a certain string. In my main activity when I need to retrieve this setting's value I call the `getString(key)` method on the `SharedPreferences` object, where `key` is the key of an `EditTextPreference`.

Now I really wonder if `setSummary` also sets the value of a preference in `SharedPreferences` by the same key to the value that I pass to `setSummary`, because I really never created a `SharedPreferences.Editor` object and called a `putString` method on it explicitly.

The docs don't say anything specific other than:

> Sets the summary for this Preference with a CharSequence.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *summary* The summary for the preference.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setSummary(java.lang.CharSequence))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly I'm sorry that I asked this question even though one of the next lectures in the course (by Google) provided the answer, but I think it was worth it as there existed no question on SO about `Preference.setSummary()` also saving values in `SharedPreferences`.

The answer is that when the **summary is changed so is the value** in `SharedPreferences` as quoted in [this video](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1474559101/e-1643578599/m-1643578601) by Google's official Android Course:

> When the user selects an option, it's saved into SharedPreferences.

Providing some context, "user selects an option" refers to choosing an option in a `ListPreference` which is then set as its summary.